# Handling overlapped divs in my XML reader function in Javascript, using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make some kind of XML reader in Javascript. The goal of that program is to create a form from an xml file in a somewhat dynamical way, that should technically handle any kind of form.

This is what my XMLreader function looks like :

```
'use strict'

$(document).ready(function()
{

    $.ajax( 
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: ".\\test.xml",
        //async: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml)
        {
            let idDiv = 0;  
            let idRadio = 0;

            $.parseXML(xml);
            $(xml).find('div').each(function()
            {
                const formDiv = document.createElement("div");
                formDiv.className = $(this).attr('name');
                setBorder(formDiv, $(this).find('border').attr('color'), $(this).find('border').attr('style'), $(this).find('border').attr('width'));
                formDiv.id = setID($(this),[idDiv]);
                console.log(formDiv.id);
                setCoordinates(formDiv, $(this).attr("top"), $(this).attr("left"), $(this).attr('width'), $(this).attr('height'));
                formDiv.style.position = "absolute";
                $(this).find('radio').each(function()
                {
                    $(this).find('elem').each(function()
                    {
                        const radioAndLabel = document.createElement("div");
                        const rad = document.createElement('input');
                        const lab = document.createElement("label");
                        rad.setAttribute("type", "radio");
                        rad.setAttribute("value", $(this).text());
                        rad.setAttribute("name", "lewis");
                        rad.id = setID($(this),[idDiv, idRadio]);
                        console.log(rad.id);
                        lab.setAttribute("for", $(this).text());
                        lab.innerHTML = $(this).text();
                        setCoordinates(radioAndLabel, $(this).attr('top'), $(this).attr('left'));
                        radioAndLabel.appendChild(rad);
                        radioAndLabel.appendChild(lab);
                        formDiv.appendChild(radioAndLabel);
                        idRadio++;
                    });
                });
                formDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                document.body.appendChild(formDiv);
                idDiv++;
                idRadio = 0;

            });
        }
    });
});

function setCoordinates(elem, top, left, width, height)
{   
    elem.style.position = "relative";
    if (top !== undefined) 
    {                   
        elem.style.top = top;
    }
    if (left !== undefined) 
    {
        elem.style.left = left;
    }
    if (width !== undefined) 
    {                   
         elem.style.width = width;
    }
    if (height !== undefined) 
    {
         elem.style.height = height;
    }
}

function setID(elem, values)
{
    let IDstring = elem.attr("id");
    for (let i=0; i<values.length; i++)
    {
        IDstring += values[i].toString() + "_";
    }
    IDstring = IDstring.substring(0, IDstring.length - 1);
    return IDstring
}

function setBorder(elem, color, style, width)
{
        elem.style.border = color + " " + style + " " + width;
}
```

When I have two non-overlapping divs, like here :

```
<form>
    <div id="div_" name="div_" top="150px" left="150px" height="125px" width="310px">
        <border style="solid" width="3px" color="red"></border>
        <radio>
            <elem id="radio_">cercle</elem>
            <elem id="radio_" top="-20px" left="100px">carré</elem>
            <elem id="radio_" top="-20px">triangle</elem>
            <elem id="radio_" top="-40px" left="100px">rectangle</elem>
        </radio>
    </div>
    <div id="div_" name="div_" width="180px" height="45px">
    <border style="solid" width="3px" color="green"></border>
        <radio>
            <elem id="radio_">AAAA</elem>
            <elem id="radio_" top="-20px" left="100px">BBBB</elem>
            <elem id="radio_" top="-20px">CCCC</elem>
            <elem id="radio_" top="-40px" left="100px">DDDD</elem>
        </radio>
    </div>
</form>
```

[It does this, which is correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhEH9.png)

But if make overlapped divs, like with this file :

```
<form>
    <div id="div_" name="div_" top="150px" left="150px" height="125px" width="310px">
        <border style="solid" width="3px" color="red"></border>
        <radio>
            <elem id="radio_">cercle</elem>
            <elem id="radio_" top="-20px" left="100px">carré</elem>
            <elem id="radio_" top="-20px">triangle</elem>
            <elem id="radio_" top="-40px" left="100px">rectangle</elem>
        </radio>
        <div id="div_" name="div_" width="180px" height="45px">
        <border style="solid" width="3px" color="green"></border>
            <radio>
                <elem id="radio_">AAAA</elem>
                <elem id="radio_" top="-20px" left="100px">BBBB</elem>
                <elem id="radio_" top="-20px">CCCC</elem>
                <elem id="radio_" top="-40px" left="100px">DDDD</elem>
            </radio>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[It does this, which is not what I want !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07EJD.png) When I overlap my divs, I expect the inner div to be contained inside the main one. But in this case, my inner div is read twice, and I end up with a div at the top left corner of my window (that I don't want).

I totally fail to think about any solution. Any idea of how I could solve that issue ?

Comment: What is an imbricated div? Does it mean overlapping perchance?

Comment: @AndyG specifically overlapping in the form of roof tiles.  These just look like they overlap.

Comment: Could it be because `id`s must be unique, but your inner div has the same id as the outer one: `id="div_"`.   TBH, it's a bit hard to tell what your doing and where and what you want to achieve / not achieve.  Is the HTML you've provided the XML source?  Is it the final rendered HTML?  Can you setup an [mcve] so it can be seen in action?

Comment: @freedomn-m The "HTML" is the XML. IDs are actually completed by the javascript code, so while they are written the same in the XML, the JS file actually takes care of giving a unique ID to every element (bar from maybe one that I could have forgotten).

What do you mean by final rendered HTML ?

I will try to set up an example.

Comment: @AndyG Yes. My bad.

Comment: I managed to pull out something smaller. It should be easier to follow now.